# Keeping b-leg on line after a-leg hangs up

Tags: freeswitch

I have a situation where I need to keep the b-leg on the line after the a-leg hangs up so that the b-leg can be presented with an IVR menu. Is this possible to do? Can it be done purely in the dialplan XML or is a different approach, e.g. a Lua script or similar, required? If the latter an example would be helpful.

I have tried using the following channel variables to do this without success:

- transfer_after_bridge
- exec_after_bridge_app / exec_after_bridge_arg

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure to export the variable to the b-leg?

```
<action application="export" data="transfer_after_bridge=1000:XML:default"/>
```

I believe this should work, but I am not 100% sure. I have not tested.